# Generic vectors in rust

Tags: rust

What are some ways of creating generic N-dimensional vectors in rust?

What I tried:

```
struct Vec<N,T> where N: u32{
    dim: N,
    data: T
}
pub type Vec2<T> = Vec<2,T>;
pub type Vec3<T> = Vec<3,T>;
```

That is at least how I did in C++. But it is not working here for some reasons:

```
error[E0404]: expected trait, found builtin type `u32`
 --> main.rs:1:26
  |
1 | struct Vec<N,T> where N: u32{
  |                          ^^^ not a trait
error[E0747]: constant provided when a type was expected
 --> main.rs:5:24
  |
5 | pub type Vec2<T> = Vec<2,T>;
  |
```

Maybe I am still thinking in C++ template style. What I don't want to do is this:

```
// pub type Vec2<T> = [T;2];
// pub type Vec3<T> = [T;3];
```

Because if I do it in this way, I should have separate functions for each dimension (vec2_add, vec3_add, vec2_cross, etc)

How can I make this in the most generic way possible? In the end, I just wanna define a vector like Vec2 or Vec3 and a single `add` or `dot` or `cross` method that will work for both

Comment: You may want to look at the [heapless::Vec](https://docs.rs/heapless/latest/heapless/struct.Vec.html) implementation, they are a good example of using const generics for size.

Comment: Note that `N-dimensional` doesn't mean what you describe - 2-dimensional `Vec` is `Vec<Vec<T>>` (or `[[T; X]; Y]`), not `[T; 2]`. You might get irrelevant answers, if someone gets confused here.

Comment: I'm actually referring to the mathematical definition of a vector when I'm saying N-dimensional @Cerberus

Answer (score 2):

You can use const generics for this:

```rust
struct Vec<const N: usize, T> {
    data: [T;N],
}

impl<const N: usize, T> Vec<N, T> {
    // your functions here
}

let my_int_vec = Vec { data: [1, 2, 3] }; // Vec<3, i32>
let my_str_vec = Vec { data: ["foo", "bar"] }; // Vec<2, &str>
```